# Linux: Deleting old log files recursively

Tags: linux, debian, file-management

I have a directory `/home/projects/` with several nested sub-directories.

How to recursively **delete all files older than 1 week inside any `logs` directory** starting from `/home/projects/` ?

A schedulable script compatible between distros, specially debian and ubuntu is a plus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find /home/projects -mtime +7 -type f -path '*/logs/*' -delete
```

you can test the match by removing '-delete'

and if used in a cron, it's a good idea to prepend it all with `nice` for lower cpu/io priority